# Concatenate string to integer inside of Get-WmiObject table - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

I want to add "GB" to each instance of "Size" so each output shows "8GB". I'm not sure how to add or concatenate a string to the integer within the table...

I have tried simply adding `+"GB"`, assigning "GB" to a variable then adding `+ $GB`. But get back `Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.`

Input:

```
$RAM = Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $Computer |
        select DeviceLocator,Manufacturer,PartNumber, @{n="Size";e={[math]::truncate($_.Capacity / 1073741824)}},Speed | FT -AutoSize
Write-Output $RAM
```

Output:

```
DeviceLocator Manufacturer PartNumber         Size Speed
------------- ------------ ----------         ---- -----
DIMM1         000000000000                       8  1600
DIMM2         000000000000                       8  1600
DIMM3         000000000000                       8  1600
DIMM4         000000000000                       8  1600
```

Comment: `[math]::truncate($_.Capacity / 1gb).ToString() + "GB"`

Comment: @AbrahamZinala That worked, thank you! Just so I understand, basically it turns it into a string then adds another string to it? Also, I did not know I could use `1gb` instead of typing out `1073741824`. Thanks twicefold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many options for this:

- [`String Formatting`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-powershell-and-basic-string-formatting/)

```
@{n="Size";e={'{0}GB' -f ($_.Capacity / 1Gb)}}
```

- [`Subexpression operator $( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#subexpression-operator--)

```
@{n="Size";e={"$($_.Capacity / 1Gb)GB"}}
```

- [`String Concatenation with + Operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-7.1)

```
@{n="Size";e={$($_.Capacity / 1Gb).ToString()+'GB'}}
```

Note here is needed to call the `.ToString()` method as suggested by [Abraham](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69760882/concatenate-string-to-integer-inside-of-get-wmiobject-table-powershell#comment123310630_69760882) in his comment or you would end up with an empty property or even worst:

```
PS \> 1+'a'
Cannot convert value "a" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

- Casting `[string]` to the operation also works here:

```
@{n="Size";e={[string]($_.Capacity / 1Gb)+'GB'}}
```

- Using the [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-7.1) Operator, pretty unorthodox for this use case but works

```
@{n="Size";e={-join (($_.Capacity / 1Gb), 'GB')}}
```